# Select all columns with GROUP BY one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table:

```
+----+-----+----------+
| id | name| key      |
+----+-----+----------+
| 1  | foo |111000    |
| 2  | bar |111000    |
| 3  | foo |000111    |
+----+-----+----------+
```

Is there a way to group by the key to get this result?

```
+----+-----+----------+
| id | name| key      |
+----+-----+----------+
| 2  | bar |111000    |
| 3  | foo |000111    |
+----+-----+----------+
```

Or this result:

```
+----+-----+----------+
| id | name| key      |
+----+-----+----------+
| 1  | foo |111000    |
| 3  | foo |000111    |
+----+-----+----------+
```

If I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sch.mytable GROUP BY(key);
```

This is not correct I know that, because I should group by all the columns that I need to show.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: You need an aggregate function to use group by. What's your aggregate function?

Comment: What aggregate function you required? Mean count or min or max or anything else

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
select distinct on (key) *
from t
order by key, name
```

Notice that the `order by` clause determines which row will win the ties.

Answer (score 28):

A query that works for all DB engines would be

```
select t1.*
from sch.mytable t1
join
(
    SELECT min(id) as id
    FROM sch.mytable 
    GROUP BY key
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

where `min(id)` is the function that influences which result you get. If you use `max(id)` you get the other.

Comment: For others: In this example 'id' is the 'primary key' column of  mytable. (I may be wrong, but That's what I assumed and query worked fine)

Comment: Just to note, `join` is the same thing as `inner join` as depicted [here](https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*YhYiJJnQLr5Z7PBKNakN2Q.png)